# How to fetch iOS crash logs programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, crash-log

I am looking to retrieve the crash logs in iPhone programmatically.
Under iOS 10 and above, the list of logs can be found here :

```
Settings --> Privacy -->Analytics --> Analytics Data-->logfiles.json
```

Is it possible to access the log files programmatically.
I am basically looking to get all the files that are found in the data section.**Not** just the files related to my app.

Note : I am not looking here for Appstore approval.

Comment: Yeah, its possible to get all crash logs programatically

Comment: Can you explain how?.....

Answer (score 2):

There is no public or private API to collect the crash reports iOS generates. On Jailbroken devices you should be able to go to the file system folder where iOS stores them and collect them directly from there. (You would need to find this folder as I don't know the exact location right now, but it is probably similar to where macOS stores them)

Answer (score 0):

You can collection  this log via Fabric -such as Crashlytic and Answer ..

Answer (score 0):

While Fabric/Crashlytics is nice, it does not support watchOS.

If you need watchOS support and more flexibility in regards to where you send the reports, check out KSCrash @ https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash